# TypeError: (function) takes exactly x arguments (x+1 given)

Tags: python, function, typeerror

I'm a very very beginner programmer doing some simple data analysis for fun. It's been a few months since I've done anything with Python, so I'm sure it's clunky and inelegant, and it wouldn't surprise me if there are big problems.

This is the function that's giving me trouble:

```
def growth (city, percentage):
    neww = int(city + city * percentage)
    return neww
```

Then the rest of the bones of the code:

```
def printStyle (cityName, cityString):
    print cityName+": "+str(cityString)

newYork=19831858
losAngeles=13052921
chicago=9522434
y=2012

while y<2020:
    newYork = growth(newYork, 0.0135)
    losAngeles = growth(losAngeles, 0.0175)
    chicago = growth(chicago, 0,0065)

print "Year: "+str(y)
printStyle ("New York", newYork)
printStyle ("Los Angeles", losAngeles)
printStyle ("Chicago", chicago)
```

And here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 49, in <module>
TypeError: growth() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

I'm using Python 2.7. What do you think?

Comment: Isn't the error should be "TypeError: growth() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)"

Comment: When Python tells you there's an error on line 49, you should start by looking there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the `,` after `0` in this line:

```
chicago = growth(chicago, 0.0065)
```

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot. Thank you! Obviously that solved it. My current editor doesn't display line numbers, so I had been miscounting. Good thing that wasn't further down, I have data on about 40 cities.

Comment: @user2439108, why on earth are you using an editor that doesn't display line numbers???

Comment: @gnibbler he could be a hardcore `cat` user

Answer (score 2):

```
chicago = growth(chicago, 0,0065)
```

There's a comma as your decimal separator there.